# how to get system or user temp folder in unix and windows?

Tags: c++

I am writing a C++ problem. It need to work on both Windows and Unix OS.

How to get user or system tmp folder on different OS?

Comment: Don't write more problems, we have enough of those already. Write a solution for once. :-)  Do you need the actual temp folder, or just a temporary file? C++ doesn't have a notion of a file system, so there are no "folders", but you can use `tmpfile` or `tmpnam` to get a temporary file.

Comment: And on Windows the equivalent function is [`GetTempFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364991%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: The `tmpfile` function doesn't give you a name; the `tmpnam` function gives you a name but isn't secure (see `mkstemp()` which gives you both a name and a file descriptor - and is secure).

Comment: @KerrekSB now cpp has https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Answer (score 53):

Update: Thanks @RoiDanton, the most up to date answer is [`std::filesystem::temp_directory_path`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path) (C++17)

---

Try [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/)'s [`temp_directory_path()`](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#temp_directory_path) which internally uses:

- *ISO/IEC 9945 (POSIX)*: The path supplied by the first environment variable found in the list `TMPDIR`, `TMP`, `TEMP`, `TEMPDIR`. If none of these are found, `"/tmp"`, or, if macro `__ANDROID__` is defined, `"/data/local/tmp"`
- *Windows*: The path reported by the Windows [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function.

Interestingly, Window's [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) uses similar logic to the POSIX version: the first environment variable in the list `TMP`, `TEMP`, `USERPROFILE`. If none of these are found, it returns the Windows directory.

The fact that these methods primarily rely on environment variables seems a bit yuck. But thats how it seems to be determined. Seeing as how mundane it really is, you could easily roll your own using `cstdlib`'s `getenv` function, especially if you want specific order prioritization/requirements or dont want to use another library.

Comment: This is the best multiplatform answer, it shoud be accepted.

Comment: Furthermore with C++14/C++17 it is part of the C++ standard: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path

Answer (score 10):

Use the [`$TMPDIR`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) environment variable, according to POSIX.

```
char const *folder = getenv("TMPDIR");
if (folder == 0)
    folder = "/tmp";
```

Comment: Using an environment variable has all sorts of gotchas, though. They may not be available in certain elevated privilege situations, or they may be maliciously changed by an adversary (or inattention)...

Comment: Yes there are security issues - but there isn't a standard alternative that I know of that is more widely available.  You could (possibly should) create a secure sub-directory in the temporary directory (especially if the value is `/tmp`) to hold the files.  Note that POSIX requires that if the pathname 'names a symbolic link, `mkdir(2)` shall fail and set errno to [EEXIST]'. Linux says that `mkdir(2)` generates EEXIST when 'pathname already exists (not necessarily as a directory). This includes the case where pathname is a symbolic link, dangling or not.' So, creating a directory is safe.

Comment: **`TMP`** for Windows, not `TMPDIR`

Answer (score 4):

if you use QT(Core) you can try `QString QDir::tempPath()` , or use it's implementation in your code (QT is open, so, check how they do).

The doc say : On Unix/Linux systems this is usually /tmp; on Windows this is usually the path in the TEMP or TMP environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the max path is MAX_PATH (260). If the path happens to be 260, the code in the sample above (als plougy) will fail because 261 will be returned. Probably the buffer size should be MAX_PATH + 1.

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
DWORD result = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH + 1, szPath);
if (result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    // check GetLastError()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Handy function :

```
std::string getEnvVar( std::string const & key )
{
    char * val = getenv( key.c_str() );
    return val == NULL ? std::string("") : std::string(val);
}
```

I guess TEMP or something could be passed as an argument? Depending on the OS of course. getenv is part of stdlib so this should also be portable.

Answer (score -1):

If you get an access to main() function code, may be better is to put necessary folder names through the main()'s **argv and use an OS-dependend batch launcher.
For example, for UNIX

```
bash a_launcher.sh
```

where a_launcher.sh is like

```
./a.out /tmp
```

Answer (score -1):

On **Windows**: Use **GetTempPath()** to retrieve the path of the directory designated for temporary files.

```
wstring TempPath;
wchar_t wcharPath[MAX_PATH];
if (GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH, wcharPath))
  TempPath = wcharPath;
```

Answer (score -1):

None of these examples are really concrete and provide a working example (besides  std::filesystem::temp_directory_path) rather they're referring you to microsoft's documentation, here's a working example using "GetTempPath()" (tested on windows 10):

```
//temp.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


int main()
{ 
    TCHAR path_buf[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD ret_val = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH, path_buf);
    if ( ret_val > MAX_PATH || (ret_val == 0) )
    {
        std::cout << "GetTempPath failed";
    } else {
        std::cout << path_buf;
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
C:\>temp.exe
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\
```